# how to give php-xml total count id

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xml, foreach

i have problem with xml and i am working with php. For me need total id. With this code get total id all products.

```
$xmlArray = array();
foreach($xml->Product as $product) { $xmlArray[] = array("productID" => (string)$product->Book); }
$total = count($xmlArray);
```

But for me need only php books total id, my codes for php books total id

```
$xmlArray2 = array();
foreach($xml->Product as $product2) { $xmlArray2[] = array("PHP" => (string)$product->Book); }
$total = count($xmlArray2);
```

but give total id all products. And all codes:

```
$inPage = 10;
$currentRecord = 10;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('http://examplesite.com/xmlinfo.xml', 0, true);

$xmlArray = array();

foreach($xml->Product as $product) { $xmlArray[] = array("prouctID" => (string) $product->Book); }

$total = count($xmlArray);

$toplamPage = ceil($total / $inPage);

foreach($xml->Product as $value) {

        if($value->Book == "PHP") {
            $currentRecord += 1;
            if($currentRecord > ($page * $inPage) && $currentRecord < ($page * $inPage + $inPage)) {
                echo '<div class="BrandTab">';
                echo '<a href="product.php?productID=' . $value->UrunID . '"><img src="' . $value->ImageName . '" style="width:130px;height:200px;/></a>';
                echo '<article>';
                echo '<div class="ok"></div>';
                echo '<p>' . $value->ProductName . '</p>';
                echo '</article>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show me $xml->Product value ?

Comment: How ? I don't understand

Comment: sample xml content which is stored in $xml ?

Comment: stored $xmlArray = array();
foreach($xml->Product as $product) { $xmlArray[] = array("productID" => (string)$product->Book); }
$total = count($xmlArray);

Comment: just echo $xml and see the output .

Comment: not have output. why ?

Comment: go to brower inspector and see html.

Comment: yes i see, so much line have but lines empty :(

Comment: what does this line do $xmlArray[] = array("productID" => (string)$product->Book); Please explain ?

Comment: don't know, because i seen on one website answer. how can make this problem ?

Comment: but working when me need total product: $xmlArray = array();
foreach($xml->Product as $product) { $xmlArray[] = array("productID" => (string)$product->Book); }
$total = count($xmlArray); this line give me total product but for only php book not working

Comment: how will you find a product is PHP in xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$xmlArray2 = array();
foreach($xml->Product as $product2) {
    if( (string)$product->Book == 'PHP' ) {
        $xmlArray2[] = array("PHP" => (string)$product->Book);
    }
}
$total = count($xmlArray2);
```

Answer (score 1):

With DOM and XPath you can fetch the value directly using DOMXpath::evaluate(). You can fetch a filtered list of the products, too. Compared to using API functions you are able to avoid a lot of loops and conditions.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Book>PHP</Book>
  <Product>
  </Product>
    <Book>JavaScript</Book>
  </Product>
</Products> 
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

var_dump($xpath->evaluate('count(//Product[normalize-space(Book) = "PHP"])'));

var_dump($xpath->evaluate('//Product[normalize-space(Book) = "PHP"]')->length);
```

#### Output

```
float(1)
int(1)
```

### Xpath Expressions

- Fetch all `Product` elements ...
   
  `//Product`
- ... with the `Book` elements equal to `PHP`...
   
  `//Product[Book = 'PHP']`
- ... after normalizing the whitespaces ...
   
  `//Product[normalize-space(Book) = 'PHP']`
- ... and return the node count as number:
  `count(//Product[normalize-space(Book) = 'PHP'])`